# How to run a containerized java application from a GitHub action

Tags: docker, github-actions, jib

I have a complex transformation that I need to apply whenever a particular file is pushed to GitHub. The transfomation is written in Kotlin (Java) and containerized using Jib. That all works ok.
The problem is I don't know how to run the containerized java app from within a GitHub action. The GitHub action is defined as

```
# This is a workflow that transforms a data file into a json file

name: file-transform
# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  container-test-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: docker.io/apigeneration/github-action-test
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
      volumes:
        - /config:/config
        - /data:/data
    steps:
      - name: Run docker application
        run: ???
```

I have tried all the options I can think of for the `run` step but the action fails.
Part of the problem is that I'm not clear how Jib defines the app entry point and so how to define  a `java` command as part of the run step (I've tried all the options I can think of based on the Jib documentation).
Just running the docker container automatically runs the java app so perhaps there's a better way to invoke it in the action though the container is is a private registry so I have to be able to pass in credentials.
Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same question, the answer is

```
  - name: Run docker application
    run: java -cp @/app/jib-classpath-file @/app/jib-main-class-file arg1 arg2
```

The args are optional, depending on the java program.